# How to handle status of a network request with LiveData, ViewModel and update UI accordingly

Tags: android, mvvm

Using Retrofit I am able to get the list of users but in case of errors, how should I manage to send notifications to UI.

I am using Android architecture components 'ViewModel', 'LiveData' in MVVM pattern and Retrofit as network library.

Comment: Hey Sharad, would you mind giving us some code? You are able to send i.e POST users to your remote backend am I right?

Comment: I would advise if you are going to use ArchitectureComponents and Retrofit, if you want to handle errors to and from your Network Requests. Create was is known as a Repository. A repository will just be an abstraction between your ViewModel and Backend. It will faciliate all your CRUD operations and pass them to your viewmodel. Check this link
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

Comment: @martinomburajr  I am fetching the list of users using retrofit from backend. If request is successful all good, UI is getting the list of users via repository and viewmodel. But in case of errors (if any), I don't know how to send the error notifications to UI. I am using the same architecture as its given in this link.  developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.htm‌​l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer for my question. Official document itself provides answer for this.
[Use Resource along with NetworkBoundResource to achieve this.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html#addendum)

Direct link:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html#addendum

Answer (score 2):

When network request completes successfully you are setting the value of livedata.
Likewise on error set the value of livedata as null and in the Activity check null before updating UI.

Further: If you want to display different types of errors to user. Create a base model class which contains basic 
Fields like error_code, error_status.

Comment: Thanks for reply but the value of livedata can be List also, so in that case creating base model won't work.

Comment: Ok what about creating a LiveData for propogating error too. Create a model class for error like I told above with fieds like error_status, wrap it up in a LiveData. Set the value of live data according to Retrofit error. (If no error null would be fine, I think). Then make your error view subscribe to the the error live data.